Response Time Logging of APIs in Rest Assured Framework
I want to log response time of different API's , where I have created multiple feature files and step definitions .
I am using this method :
public void logResponseTime(String apiName, long responseTime) throws IOException {
     try (PrintStream stream = new PrintStream(new FileOutputStream("responseTime.txt", true))) 
     { 
        stream.println(apiName + " Response Time: " + responseTime + " milliseconds");
     } 
}

It is working fine , but the results are getting overwritten every time I run the feature files, I want that after every run the new ones get overwritten by the old results.
